# Is it possible to download a large database using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am downloading files from server using WinSCP.Is it possible to write a query to download a large database using mysql query? Or using any other method
i have tried with this code but i am not able to get the whole database structure

```
<?php

              if(file_exists('backup_sql/my_backup.zip'))
               {

                unlink('backup_sql/my_backup.zip');
               }


               $tables='*';
              $host='MY HOST NAME';
              $user='MY_USERNAME';
              $pass='MYPASSWORD';
              $name='MY_DB_NAME';

         $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
          mysql_select_db($name,$link);


          if($tables == '*')
          {
            $tables = array();
            $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
              $tables[] = $row[0];
            }
          }
          else
          {
            $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
          }
          $return='';

          foreach($tables as $table)
          {
            $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
            $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);


            $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
            $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
            {
              while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
              {

                $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
                {
                  $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);


                  if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                  if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                }
                $return.= ");\n";
              }
            }
            $return.="\n\n\n";
          }



          $rand_var=time();
            $files_to_zip = array(
            "'backup_sql/db-backup-'.$rand_var.'.sql'",

          );

         $name = 'db-backup-'.$rand_var.'.sql';
$data = $return;



?>
```

any one please help me... thank you

Answer (score 4):

if you are using SCP, you are apparently have a shell access to the server.
in this case I see no point in using any web-based tools to backup the database

just run `mysqldump`/`mysql` to dump/restore
that's all

Comment: even with out shell access exec('mysqldump ...');

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`set_time_limit(0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in the beginnig of your code.

Answer (score 1):

PHP scripts cannot run indefinitely, that is : after a pre-specified amount of time (as defined in the `php.ini` file), *usually 60 seconds*, the script will terminate and a `Timeout` error will be thrown.

**The ways to go are :**

- Either use `set_time_limit(0)` at the beginning of your script to override the settings in your `php.ini` files, and have the script run indefinitely (quite an overkill, if you ask me)
- Tweak the settings in `php.ini` file and the `max_execution_time` variable (quite an overkill, as well)
- ***Recommended :*** Use the `mysqldump` command, via SSH (Secure SHell connection). :-)

Comment: i have script that runs for a week already. what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Maybe, what I'm doing... wrong, too : http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/running-background-processes-in-php-349/

Comment: I am running it as a standalone process, not as a child of web-server process.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Even then, why would it be wrong? I mean, other than putting an extra load on your server... (well, that pretty much depends on what the script does; if it's been running for a week trying to find Mersenne primes, then I suppose this could be a bit too much... lol)

Comment: you just said PHP scripts cannot run indefinitely, so, I thought I did something wrong

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm just saying that PHP scripts are normally limited because of server settings (probably, to avoid having the server crash when something goes.. wrong and a script is "not responding")... (p.s. You're quite a tease! lol)

Answer (score 0):

No, Timeout will occur. There is default limit of time for which a script can execute.

That is defined under `max_execution_time` PHP ini settings. you can increase it's value and try.